# Incrementing a date in javascript, in order to update MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, date

In MongoDB collection I have 3 objects. I need to update one variable (date type) in each object. The main task is to increment the date of the objects. For example:  all objects have the same variable:

```
"Time1" : ISODate("2016-01-12T21:37:46.738Z")
```

My problem is to update the first object with the current date, manually I do it in this way:

`$db.getCollection('my.data')({'_id':ObjectId("52e637fca92cf1ec6a73c1e8")}, {$currentDate: {Time1: true}})`

The next is to increase the date of the second object by 1 day, I mean to update it with tomorrow date. I couldn't do it through the shell, because $inc doesn't work with Date type. 
So, I am lost with javascript

I found how to get it with java script but I don't know how to collect all if this in one script.

```
var tomorrow = new Date();
tomorrow.setDate(today.getDate()+1);
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the **[`$set`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/)** operator for the other fields, together the the **[`$currentDate`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/currentDate/#up._S_currentDate)** operator all within the update object:

```
var tomorrow = new Date();
tomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate()+1);

var dayAfterTomorrow = new Date();
dayAfterTomorrow.setDate(dayAfterTomorrow.getDate()+2);

db.getCollection("my.data").update(
    { "_id": ObjectId("52e637fca92cf1ec6a73c1e8") },
    { 
        "$currentDate": { "Time1": true },
        "$set": {
            "Time2": tomorrow,
            "Time3": dayAfterTomorrow
        }
    }
)
```